# Model evaluation in Stanford NER

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm doing a project with the NER module from Stanford CoreNLP and I'm currently having some issues with the evaluation of the model.

I'm using the API to call the functionality from inside a java program instead of using the command line arguments and so far I've managed to train the model from several training files (in a tab-separated format; 2 columns with token and annotation/answer) and to serialize it to a file which was pretty easy.

Now I'm trying to evaluate the model I've trained on some test files (precision, recall, f1) and I'm kinda stuck there. First of all, what format should the test files be in? I'm assuming they should be the same as the training files (tab-separated) which would be the logical thing. I've looked through the JavaDoc documentation for information on how to use the `classify` method and also had a look at the NERDemo.java. I've managed to get the `classifyToString` method to work but that doesn't really help me with the evaluation. I've found the `classifyAndWriteAnswers(String testFile, DocumentReaderAndWriter<IN> readerWriter, boolean outputScores)` method that I assume would give me the precision and recall scores if I set `outputScores` to true.

However, I can't manage to get this to work. Which `DocumentReaderAndWriter` should I use as the second argument?

This is what I've got right now:

```
public static void evaluate(CRFClassifier classifier, File testFile) {
        try {
            classifier.classifyAndWriteAnswers(testFile.getPath(), new PlainTextDocumentReaderAndWriter(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is what I get:

```
Unchecked call to 'classifyAndWriteAnswers(String, DocumentReaderAndWriter<IN>, boolean)' as a member of raw type 'edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier'
```

Also, do I pass the path to the test file as the first argument or rather the file itself loaded into a String? Some help would be greatly appreciated.